# Where can I ask questions on social media?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask questions on how to make my social media usage more efficient.

Questions like:

- Ask for tips
- How to get more facebook-page fans or twitter followers
- Which tools are available for facebook and/or twitter users to get insights on their social media activities.

Where can I ask such questions?

Answer (score 2):

I feel that your questions, in their current form, are too broad for a focused Q&A site in the Stack Exchange network.

If you manage to specify **detailed requirements** for the tool you seek in your third question, you might be able to get help on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Just asking for a tool is too broad as well, you need to specify [enough information](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

If you need help with specific features of a Social Media application, this is covered by [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Trying for the Lifesaver hat? :P

Comment: Actually, that's one of the best designed hats (from a functionality perspective).

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, on my main site, there have been *no* tumbleweeds awarded *ever*.

Comment: Well, this one won't work either. The user hasn't been seen since Sep 14.

Comment: So are we saying there is no way to ask marketing related questions on the Stack sites?  Because there's always more than 1 way to achieve a result and multiple ways may be the right answer?